# Dataframe Iterative calculations and merging in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, foreach, merge

I have the following sample  type of data frame with many rows and columns. I need to take the average of the previous rows and add it to the other column with loop in  R.

Input:

```
MA1 MA2 MA3 MA4 MA5
4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
3.0 4.0 0.2 3.0 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
0.2 4.0 1.0 0.2 2.0
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2
5.0 4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2
```

Output:

```
MA1 MA2 MA3 MA4 MA5  MA6 MA7  MA8  MA9  MA10 MA11
4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 2.80 2.80 2.80 2.80 2.80 2.80
3.0 4.0 0.2 3.0 0.2 2.09 2.09 2.09 2.09 2.09 2.09
0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22 0.22
0.2 4.0 1.0 0.2 2.0 1.49 1.49 1.49 1.49 1.49 1.49
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78
5.0 4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 1.93 1.93 1.93 1.93 1.93 1.93
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78 0.78
```

Here the MA6 should be the average column values from MA1 to MA5  and 
         MA7 should be average column values from MA1 to MA6 and so on... Can anyone help me in solving this

Comment: Are you aware that MA6 to MA11 are the same columns?

Comment: Yeah! I am aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowMeans` isn't a great example here since your values will not change after the first iteration, but try this recursive function

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="MA1 MA2 MA3 MA4 MA5
4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
3.0 4.0 0.2 3.0 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
0.2 4.0 1.0 0.2 2.0
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2
5.0 4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2
0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2", header=TRUE)
```

Recursive function

```
myfun <- function(df, N, counter) {
            require(dplyr)
            if (counter > N) {
                return(df)  # return value once number of iterations is fulfilled
            } else {
                new.df <- df %>% 
                        mutate(new = rowMeans(.)) %>%  # modify data frame
                        rename_at(vars("new"), funs(paste0("MA", ncol(df)+1)))  # rename new column
                myfun(new.df, N, counter+1)  # recursive, calls function again but with modified data frame
            }
         }

myfun(df, N=5, counter=1)

  # MA1 MA2 MA3 MA4 MA5  MA6  MA7  MA8  MA9 MA10
# 1 4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.96 0.96 0.96 0.96 0.96
# 2 3.0 4.0 0.2 3.0 0.2 2.08 2.08 2.08 2.08 2.08
# 3 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20
# 4 0.2 4.0 1.0 0.2 2.0 1.48 1.48 1.48 1.48 1.48
# 5 0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2 0.76 0.76 0.76 0.76 0.76
# 6 5.0 4.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.92
# 7 0.2 0.2 0.2 3.0 0.2 0.76 0.76 0.76 0.76 0.76
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. What if I had extra rows in my original data set and don't want to include in my calculation of mean?

Comment: I would still calculate the rowMeans for every row, and simply ignore or change those values at the end that you want to ignore

Comment: Got it! Thank you once again.